# SSRS Calculated field with IIF expression gives #error when the condition is false

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, rdlc, ssrs-tablix

Hello I'm fairly new to SSRS and I'm working on making my first report for work. It has been going fine until today when I needed make a textbox in Tablix handle both a numbers calculation and text. A column in my SQL table that was previously a purely number field now has n|a for certain rows. So I wrote the following expression to handle those n|as. When the proceeds field is numeric the formula works, but when it's an n|a it shows up on the report as #error and I can't figure out why. I've removed all formatting from the textbox to the same result.

```
=IIF(Fields!Proceeds.Value<>"n|a",Fields!Proceeds.Value / Fields!DealBalance.Value,"n|a")
```

Comment: Can you confirm this is vb.net and not vba?

Comment: you're mixing strings and numbers as output

Comment: @soohoonigan `IIF` allows it. The output is Object... if this is vb.net. The code could be either .net or vba however...

Comment: @djv I'm pretty sure it's Visual Basic, it's whatever language rdlc reports use

Comment: @djv, this is RDLC expression code for a report.  It is based VB.Net, but with a preference for using the older style VBA functions. See [Expression Examples (Report Builder and SSRS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15#VisualBasicFunctions) for an overview.

Comment: @TnTinMn does the IIF behave the same as VB.NET IIF? The linked reference isn't clear about that.

Comment: OP, `IIF` is a function and as such the passed parameters are evaluated for both the true and false parts.  So if `Fields!Proceeds.Value` is a string, you are doing a  division operation on a string that fails.  This would be a case for embedding a custom VB.Net function in the report that can use better type inspection functions.

Comment: @djv, yes it does.  See above comment.

Comment: @TnTinMn right, the fact that it always evaluates both results is the issue. Good catch.

Comment: @djv, not that good of a catch as I totally overlooked that the OP is storing numeric values as strings in the database just to allow entering "n/a" versus using a nullable numeric field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As TnTinMn explained, IIF always evaluates both the true and false part of the expression.

The simple fix is to do something like
**EDIT** Revised due to update from OP

```
=IIF(Fields!Proceeds.Value<>"n|a",VAL(REPLACE(REPLACE(Fields!Proceeds.Value,",",""),"$","")) / Fields!DealBalance.Value,"n|a")
```

This simply strips out the $ symbol and commas and then converts the text to a number using VAL(), if the text is not a number it will return zero which will not cause an error as the false part of your expression would give 0/DealBalance.

Comment: This solved the #error issue when the result was n|a, but now when the proceeds field is actually a number it returns 0.00%

Comment: can you give me an example of a number for both Proceeds and dealbalance in your dataset including any formatting (currency symbols etc). It should work.

Comment: The Proceeds data looks like [$1,230,518,650 , n|a , $1,218,620,302 ] and the dealbalance data looks like [1200506100 , 964898000 , 1177528300]

Comment: The resulting Output for those three rows should be [102.5% , n|a , 103.5%]

Comment: I've updated the answer, now the expression will strip out commas and the $ symbol before applying VAL(). I've tested with this data and it works as expected

Comment: You're wlecome - (hero worship not required !)  :)

Comment: @CurtisRhoa storing numbers in your database as text is what causes the issue. You may not understand it at this point.